# DRF and Angular form validation

Tags: angularjs, django, forms, validation, django-rest-framework

i have some simple questions which i am stuck and i really need some help. For my project i am using Django Rest Framework for server side and AngularJs for Client side.

My questions are: i am making form validation in client side with angular,

1) Do i have to validate and in server side, because if someone access my api endpoint, could register users very easily,
2) How to validate in server side.

My cloudy view is that i don't know very good how does angular and django rest communicate with each other

Thank you.

Comment: They normally communicate via JSON over AJAX.  You need to do validation on both sides. On client, because you want the user to get instant feedback, and on the server, because you don't want malicious users to submit bad data to your API by hand-crafting AJAX requests to your API that your client code didn't write.

Comment: can someone show me how to validate that "POST" data in server side using Django Rest Framework and insert it into database ? i am really stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

You can do both client and server validation. In Bootstrap/Angular you can make the validation with tag 'required'.

When you send the data from front end to backend, if there is an error, which DRF is going to send back to client, you can show/handle this error in angular call something lit below.

```
SomeService.CreateEntry.then(function success(data){
                   // Do append a bootstrap success message on the client side
              }, function error(msg) {
                    // Do append a bootstrap error strip to show the server error on the client side 
              });  
};
```

Usually while doing a PUT/POST, if there is any error on server, the error message is given as json with fields as key.. In the service while calling the API, you can do something like the below.

```
   $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: url,
          headers: {......},
          data : data_to_server,  
        })
          .success(function (data) {
            return data;
          })
          .error(function (error) {
            return error;
          });

  }
```